# Vertices of an object rotate on different axis

Tags: vertices, origin

I recently downloaded a bitcoin model from cgtrader.

The problem being that the vertices of this model seem to have several different origins, so if I rotate the object in edit mode, the object doesn't keep its initial shape...

Do you know what to do in this case ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

set transform pivot point to median
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try this !

Comment: It works !! TY !!